# MAMP PRO with Typo3 and Fluid image is not rescaling

Tags: typo3, fluid, mamp-pro

I'm setting up my test server with MAMP PRO on my Mac. In one of the virtual host I have an Typo3 installation running. On this Typo3 website I would like to have an image rescaled but this is not working, code works fine on the production server. It shows the image in the original size. The following fluid code is used:

```
<f:image src="{slide.imageUrl}" width="1000c" height="120c" />
```

I enabled imagick in MAMP PRO, doubled checked with phpinfo() and this is ok. Does anyone have an idee?

Comment: This looks like the error code from the php error log:                                        [06-Nov-2015 13:58:44 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Go to the terminal and write `which convert` it should you show you the path like `/usr/local/bin/convert` so go to the Install tool and use it for `[GFX][im_path]` (folder only, w/out command) - `/usr/local/bin/` in this sample. After save go to Test Setup (in install tool) and verify that scalling is working

Comment: Indead the comand gave back "/usr/local/bin/convert". But the valiable [GFX][im_path] was already set to "/usr/local/bin/" so it is still not working on the website. In the backend test the images are scaling correctly.

Comment: Now it works, the images where cashed even after clearing the cash. Thanks @biesior for the help.